# VB.net logarithmic charts starting from 0.1

Tags: vb.net, charts, logarithm

what I need is a logarithmic chart in VB.NET that also shows values that are smaller then 1. I set the minimum to 0.01 but the bars still start at 1, so there is a big gap with nothing in the chart right now. Any ideas on how to solve this one? If you need more information, please let me know. I will provide everything you need to help me.

[image]

Comment: Chart Areas > Axes > Y (Value) Axis > Scale > Crossing = Min.

Comment: chartArea.AxisY.Minimum = 0.1
chartArea.AxisY.Crossing = 0.1    results in following: [link](http://imgur.com/a/ak0mq)